# Make PC always hibernate

Tags: windows-7, hibernate

I want my pc to hibernate even when I press "shut down".

Either that, or simply remove the "shut down" button from the start menu.

Is there a way to do any of these?

Comment: OP's question hasn't been answered there, neither, even though it's the same as mine.

Comment: I don't believe there's a way to do what you're asking. The only options are to remove all options from the Start Menu (Shut Down, Reboot, Log Off, etc..) There doesn't seem to be a way to change the behavior of the Shut Down button itself.

Comment: Then I can keep "hibernate" and delete the others. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

To change the start button to something other than Shut Down

Click `Start` then right-click on `Shut Down` then click `Properties`

Under Power Button Action, change the dropdown to `Hibernate`

Comment: Still, is there any way to remove the "shut down" button from the list?

Comment: Check out this link, it should help [Disable/Remove Start Button](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-disable-remove-shutdown-from-windows-xp-and-vista/)

Comment: That method will remove hibernate, sleep, restard and shut down. I want only shut down removed.